# PNG file saved by Blender was black and then became dithered off black. Not desired

Tags: image, uv-image-editor, file-format

[image]

GIMP images to compare settings . Apologies to WHO.  Original problem and actions based on comments.  Comment becomes official answer ‼

- 3. Original Problem. Posterized Image emphasizes small variations in near black RGB(0,0,0) and RGB(1,1,1) Max 255 .
- 1. RAW format and No Dither. Good Results and minimal testing so far. See Comment.
- 2. No Dither. See Comment.

A Blender scene with a mesh was rendered with the goal of being a black and white image.  Mesh white emissive. No lights.

A black pixel will be RGB(0,0,0).  No regard for alpha channel.

Let solid black denote black pixels with all black neighbors. The goal is to have solid black pixels on screen should remain solid black pixels in the saved file.  White pixels with all white neighbors are not the concern. High frequency areas are not the concern.

If any part of the description is too difficult to follow please do not burden yourself.  You can always ↕ and save everyone time.

Image saved from Blender Render Window. A file created by Blender had black pixels in the sense the click info on the Blender window shows

RGB as (0.0000,0.0000,0.0000) max 1.0

Blender image save with no compression or voodoo and the solid black pixels became

RGB as (1,1,1) and RGB(0,0,0) max 255 Mixed ... Dithered

according to GIMP.    A small difference for humans but a giant leap for computerkind.

Is this a known property of Blender Image Save?  How can it be avoided?

The RGB value is being processed by a computer program and not by human visual inspection.

Comment: interesting. is this simply an empty scene with no lights?

Comment: Could be a color management issue. Try if turning off Filmic helps. That's in the properties editor > Render Properties tab > Color Management panel > View Transform.

Comment: Your description is a little hard to follow. What are (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) and (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) getting mapped to in the saved file? Make sure that you disable *Dithering* in *Output Properties > Post Processing* and either use OpenEXR as output format or set *View Transform* to *Raw* if it's non-color data you're trying to save and the value range in Blender is known to be [0.0, 1.0].

Comment: maybe adding some illustration could help to understand clearly what you wrote?

Comment: could be antialiasing? render properies > film > filter size to 0.

Comment: @Tiles  View Transform Changed to Raw. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertGützkow View Transform changed to Raw.  Dither changed to 0.0.  Thanks.  Comments can become answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description it seems that you want to store the scene linear values without dithering in your image.

Dithering can be disabled in *Output Properties > Post Processing* by setting the *Dither* to `0.0`.

[image: Dithering]

In order to store the exact scene linear values it would be recommended to use the *OpenEXR* or *OpenEXR Multi-layer* image format. It will store the exact scene linear values without applying the view or display transform.

[image: OpenEXR]

Alternatively, if you know that the scene linear values are within the $\left[0.0, 1.0\right]$ range, you're working with non-color data and you *don't* want to use OpenEXR as image format, then you can explicitly disable color management by setting the *View Transform* in *Render Properties > Color Management* to *Raw*.

[image: View Transform]

Comment: Unditheringly I do not want dithering.

Comment: Although I would like to see more ↕ for my original question. I hope that generates more ↕ for your answer.  Remember  thoroughly and often.  Do not 

Comment: By now you should already have 3 upvotes not 1.  I am losing faith in the Blender BLs.